# SIM900A A6 module Arduino +CME error 58

Tags: compilation-errors

I've recently bought a SIM900A A6 GSM module. Whenever I send a command it gives an error: +CME error 58.

Does anybody know what this means and how to solve it?

Comment: Post your schematic and a complete test sketch that show your problem.

Comment: I am also working on A6 and receiving the same error. I suspect it has something to do with the power supply. Will post my final answer once I have finished. Hassan (hassan.uh@gmail.com)

Comment: Which commands are you sending? From my experience it seems the command isn't supported. What happens if you issue just `AT` or `ATZ`?

Answer (score 1):

Your sim card is probably protected by a PIN. Easiest way to get it working is to put the SIM into a normal phone and remove the PIN protection.

Comment: I've already done that it is receiving text messages and calls but its still giving this error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  My error was using the incorrect baud rate.  Set the baud rate to 115200.  Also, ensure that "Both NL & CR" option is selected for new line options.  After changing those settings, I had to reboot the A7, and wait for all the status messages to complete before I could send the AT command.